# Oracle SQL: convert UTC to CST

Tags: sql, oracle, function, date, converters

I would like to convert UTC date/time to local CST.

The below function works however it gives 6 hours difference when there should only be 5 hours (until day light saving on 11/2/2014).

```
CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(utc_date AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'CST') AS DATE) cst_date
```

also tried a variation

```
to_date(to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(utc_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ,'UTC')
at time zone 'CST'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as cst_date,
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `utc_date`?

Comment: @Wernfried The data type is DATE. Need timestamp to use FROM_TZ. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions059.htm. See my last comment below with Rajesh Chamarthi.

Answer (score 2):

Using the "US/Central" as the target timezone seems to produce the right result.

```
select from_tz(CAST ('15-oct-2014' AS TIMESTAMP),'GMT') at  TIME ZONE 'US/Central' with_daylight_savings,
       from_tz(CAST ('15-nov-2014' AS TIMESTAMP),'GMT') at  TIME ZONE 'US/Central' without_daylight_savings
from dual;


WITH_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS                       WITHOUT_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-OCT-14 07.00.00.000000000 PM US/CENTRAL  14-NOV-14 06.00.00.000000000 PM US/CENTRAL
```

Comment: This gives you 5 hours difference as expected.

Comment: SELECT TO_DATE('2013-10-29 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       NEW_TIME(TO_DATE('2013-10-29 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                'GMT',
                'CDT')
  FROM DUAL;

Comment: Here I am expecting 6 hours after the day light savings time adjustment.

Comment: SELECT TO_DATE('2013-11-29 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       NEW_TIME(TO_DATE('2013-11-29 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                'GMT',
                'CDT')
  FROM DUAL;

Comment: @user3050672 - Was your comment a question? Currently Day light savings is "ON", which is why CDT is CST+1 hour.the adjustment is one hour forward. If you are looking for the correct daylight adjusted time, you should use CDT.

Comment: Yes, it was. CDT make sense but I a not getting the results that I expected. Like you said, currently the Day Light savings is on so the time difference is 5 hours, which is accurate. However, when I passed on a a date after the Day Light savings ended, i.e. 11/29/2013, I expected to see the difference at 6 hours, but that gave the same 5 hours difference.

Comment: Apprently, that is a limitation with the new_time function and from_tz with the full name of the timezone gies the expected result. Updated my query.

Comment: Back to my original question - the function from_tz works great but I am getting 6 hours difference with the current date instead of 5 hours. Try your queries with date 10/25/2014 and 10/26/2014. I am not sure why the Day Light savings happen a week earlier at Oracle.

Comment: yep, agreed. This looks wierd.

Answer (score 0):

Use timezone region instead of timezone abbr ('CST'). You may find the desired timezone here:

```
SELECT * from v$timezone_names where tzabbrev = 'CST';
```

Maybe you need 'CST6CDT' instead of 'CST'

Comment: Good point. I was hopeful that the region will fix the issue when I saw the different regions under tzabbrev = 'CST'. However, Same result when sub with region as 'America/Chicago'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid approach, but what do you get from this query?

```
SELECT 
   TO_CHAR((TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01 00:00:00' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '1' DAY) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi TZH:TZM') AS dst,
   TO_CHAR((FROM_TZ(CAST(DATE '2014-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') + LEVEL * INTERVAL '1' DAY) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi TZH:TZM') AS dst
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365;
```

Is it as expected?